# How to configure commands to get executed automatically when AWS ec2 instance cpu utilization goes above certain percentage

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am running an application on aws ec2 instance(Linux). Its cpu utilization is going to 100% and the instance is becoming unhealthy. I am not sure which request is causing the spike in the CPU utilization. I want to configure some commands to get executed automatically whenever AWS ec2 instance CPU utilization goes above 80%. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: What are the commands you want to run? Specifically, are they commands on the instance that has high CPU, or is it commands _outside_ of the instance (eg for doing something else in AWS)?

Comment: The commands on the instance that has high CPU like taking java thread dump, checking processes running and upload to s3

Comment: In that case, I would recommend writing something that runs on the instance itself (since AWS can't see what happens _inside_ an instance). This becomes a Linux question rather than an EC2 question, apart from the final step when you could use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to upload the file to S3. You might get a better response asking on https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Hello, we are facing the same problem. Please, did you find the cause of the problem? Isn't a docker container problem or other things?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this with a combination of CloudWatch Alarm, CloudWatch Event, and Lambda.

First, create a CloudWatch Alarm that will trigger whenever the EC2's `CPUUtilization` metric satisfies your condition.

[image: EC2 CPUUtilization Threshold]

From here, you can configure your Alarm to send an SNS message, perform an Auto Scaling action, or perform an EC2 action (you can choose to stop/ reboot/ terminate the instance).

If you need to execute a custom code when the Alarm triggers, then you can create a CloudWatch Event that matches `CloudWatch Alarm State Change` to trigger a Lambda function, and finally specify your custom action in your Lambda function.

[image]